If Orthodox is the true Church, why do Catholics have (apparently) genuine relics?
Roman Catholics claim to have any number of relics which are significant to the Christian faith, of which the Shroud of Turin is probably the best known. There also seem to be some strong arguments for the authenticity of the same.
If, as they claim, the Orthodox church is the "true" church, why would God allow these (apparently genuine) relics to fall into the hands of those who have fallen away, rather than preserving them for the True Church?
(I am looking primarily for Orthodox responses, though one might ask Protestants a similar question, as both believe the RCC to be in error. Also, whether the Shroud specifically is a genuine relic isn't the point as such, although "they aren't genuine relics" may be a possible answer.)

I didn't think the Orthodox considered Catholics to be apostate. Don't they consider each other to be schismatics instead?

You might as well as ask why God lets anything less than good happen. It's effectively the same thing.

Do you know for sure that the Orthodox Church recognizes Roman relics as genuine?

@RayButterworth In the past, some Orthodox Churches have exchanged relics with the Catholic Church, notably between the pope and certain Orthodox bishops.

Rome has never officially declared the Shroud of Turin as a real relic. At least not yet.

@curiousdannii you are correct. Apostasy is the total repudiation of the Christian faith. But I believe that the Orthodox consider Catholics to be heretics, while Catholics consider Orthodox to be schismatic (although I think a case can be made after Vatican I that Orthodox Christians ought to be considered heretics by Rome).

Since when did any religious group holding on to any number of 'relics' prove anything about whether their religion it 'true' or not? I comment in view of the o.p. allowing Protestants a similar question, as both believe the RCC to be in error.

@Anne, whether the possession of apparently-genuine relics lends any credence to a sect's claims to being the True Church is certainly relevant to the Question. As a Protestant, I think I'd lean toward "no", but I'm still curious whether any respected writings on the matter exist. Due to the relation between EO and RCC, I'm particularly interested in the Question from the EO's perspective.

There also seems to be some sort of assumption that belief in Orthodoxy being the one, holy, catholic, and apostolic Church means believing that there are no followers of Jesus outside of the Orthodox Church (hint: we don't believe that—we know where the Orthodox Church is, but we don't know where it is not). The Roman Catholic Church was part of the Orthodox Church until around 1054 when the Great Schism occurred. There's a lot of shared saints / holy items from before that period.
